# LibGDX, BitmapFont strange position behavior

Tags: libgdx, rendering, fonts

I'm using a Stage of LibGDX to draw a text, in my case the FPS. But after resizing, the position of the text does not behave properly.

As you can see in the attached gif:

[image]

The resizing function does work correctly. Also here is my code of the UI-renderer:

```
GameScreen screen;
BitmapFont font;

FreeTypeFontGenerator generator;
FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter parameter;

private Texture map;

public UIStage(GameScreen screen) {
    this.screen = screen;
    generator = new FreeTypeFontGenerator(Gdx.files.internal("font/acknowtt.ttf"));
    parameter = new FreeTypeFontGenerator.FreeTypeFontParameter();
    parameter.size = 24;
    parameter.borderWidth = 2;
    parameter.borderColor = new Color(0, 0, 0, 1F);
    parameter.borderStraight = true;
    font = generator.generateFont(parameter);
    this.map = new Texture(Gdx.files.internal("levels/map/" + 
        screen.map.getLevel().getName() + ".png"));
    generator.dispose();
}

@Override
public void draw() {
    this.getBatch().setColor(1F, 1F, 1F, 1F);

    this.getBatch().begin();
    this.font.draw(
        this.getBatch(), 
        "FPS: " + GameScreen.fpsLogger.getFPS(), 
        10, 
        this.getViewport().getScreenHeight() - 44);
    this.getBatch().end();
}
```

How can I make my text behave properly?